# How to duplicate a target with a Expo config plugin?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am working on a solution for an Expo white-label app. There are for example 3 versions of the app, red app, blue app and orange app. When I run prebuild an IOS and Android folder will be generated. When I open the native folder (IOS) in Xcode there will be one initial target. As first step I need to duplicate the intitial target 2 times, because there are 3 apps and one of the targets is already created (the initial target).

I did a lot of research and tried a lot of things. But I could not find a way how to do it. Anyone who has experience with writing Expo config plugin or an idea?